# Convert pixels to mm with opencv/c++ --> Distance between two points

Tags: c++, opencv

I have two points p1(x1, y1) and p2(x2, y2). Both are centers of two circles in a 2D plan.
The two circles are detected automatically in a picture taken by the user with his smartphone.

For some reasons I want to measure the distance (in meters) between p1 and p2.

I absolutely have no clue of how I can do it. I did have a look at calib3D module but I don't think I found anything useful.

The distance between the camera and the circles may vary and is nerver constant, I think this a parameter we could pay attention to ? For the calculation of the distance of the two centers.

Is there a particular way to do such a thing ?
If you have any method that could help me, I'd be grateful.

Thanks, have a nice day.

Hugo

Comment: This isn't a C++ question. It is a math question. And the answer is: you cannot. You need to know the distance to those two points aside from their the coordinates - an information you don't have. Perhaps, if you obtained it somehow then it could be possible.

Comment: @ALX23z, It is possible actually, there are some applications that are able to do it without knowing the distance to the two points aside their coordinates. Take "Mesures" from Apple it does it perfectly.

Comment: it's not a math question, it's a "I don't know that I want a toolkit for this" kind of question.

Comment: Yeah I know there's a toolkit for this kind of stuff. I've done some research, and I didn't find anything so far. No problem if you're not willing to help I'll found a way.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so,

Here are the steps to A solution :

I) First make an orthonormal plan.

I needed two build up an orthonormal plan in which I will calculate the distance between the 2 points.

I need to know the distance in centimeters, I have a picture in pixels so I need to know how many centimeters is a pixel.

In my case, the picture is 2498 x 1570 pixels.
When I measure with a ruler on the sheet taking the good corners :

2498 px = 18.2 centimeters and
1570 px = 11.4 centimeters.

With these datas we know that 1 px =~ 0.0073 centimeters. (18.2 / 2498 =~ 0.0073). (11.4 / 1570 =~ 0.0073)

II) Distance formula in an orthonormal plan

```
double Operation::distanceBetween2Points(Point A, Point B){

    double coeff = 0.0073;
    double diffx = (B.x - A.x) * coeff;
    double diffy = (B.y - A.y) * coeff;

    return sqrt(pow(diffx, 2) + pow(diffy,2));
}
```

I've found a distance equal to 0.61005 centimeters which matches the reality (= 0.6 cms).

I ran several tests, it works every times, matching the reality.

Answer (score 0):

you need to *use* an Augmented Reality toolkit. nothing less will solve the problem, unless your problem has constraints that make it simpler than stated.

such toolkits are available for Apple and Android mobile platforms.

it makes no sense for you to try to implement the core of Augmented Reality yourself. some understanding of the theory does help in using a toolkit.

Comment: Yeah sure, I need to go deeper in the opencv's manual. I'm sure it has got what I need.

Comment: In deed my problem has constraints which I think, like you said, makes it simpler to resolve than using a Augmented reality toolkit. I just asked to fasttrack things.